# Graylog: How to query multiple streams by Greylog rest API?

Tags: graylog

I want to create a Graylog rest query to search for a messages in multiple streams where message can be either in stream1 or in stream2, or stream-3, etc.

At the moment I am using endpoint called **Message search with absolute timerange**: `GET api/search/universal/absolute`

I do not know ho to create condition "message can be either in stream1 or in stream2, or stream3" condition in `filter` parameter.

Example with one stream:

```
https://graylog.example.com/api/search/universal/absolute?
query=instance:"node1"&
filter=streams:stream-1-id&        <--- How to pass multiple stream Ids here?
from=2023-01-01T00:00:00.000Z&
to=2023-07-01T00:00:00.000Z&
limit=50&
decorate=true&
fields=timestamp,message
```

`filter=streams:stream-1-id,stream-2-id` does not work, result is empty - probably AND operator is applied between streams.

Solution with a different endpoint is also possible.